# How can I create an index array in R, in which every row is a person and every column is a property

Tags: arrays, r, dataframe

This will probably be very simple but I am a beginneR and have been going to documentation and other docs without finding the answer. Arrays, matrices and dataframes are still confusing for me.

I would like to create a table or array, in which every row is, say, a person, and evey column a property (age, address). I would like to be able to retrieve the properties corresponding to a given row. Moreover, I would like to be able to input this by row, instead of by column.

I tried:

```
j <- list(name="joe", age=22, address="2 Corona street")
k <- list(name="kate", age=33, address="3 Albarn road")
employees <- list(k,l)
```

And would like then to be able to retrieve joe's address, where the name is a variable, using something along the lines of:

```
x <- "joe"
addressToRetrieve <- employees[name=x][address]
```

I realise that my syntax is probably gibberish but hopefully enough to give an idea of what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest just using a `data.frame` (or a `data.table`) instead of dealing with nested `list`s like you've done in your example--particularly if your data are "rectangular" in form.

If that's the case, you would be able to do things like:

```
employeeDF <- rbind.data.frame(j, k)
employeeDF
#    name age         address
# 2   joe  22 2 Corona street
# 21 kate  33   3 Albarn road

x <- "joe"
with(employeeDF, employeeDF[name == x, "address"])
# [1] 2 Corona street
# Levels: 2 Corona street 3 Albarn road
```

If you are going to be inputting data *by row*, I would suggest that when you create your initial `data.frame`, ensure that you use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` otherwise you might run into problems when trying to add new values.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is something called a Class. Here are some resources related to classes in R.

[R:Class Definitions](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/methods/html/Classes.html)

[PDF About Methods, Classes, And Objects](http://www.academia.edu/1972132/Object_Class_and_Method_in_R)

Additionally, you should be able to find countless resources regarding classes on any programming site.